# Spring Neo4j JPA native dynamic order by query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

I need to sort native query dynamically, I passed the Pageable object, skip and limit properties work correctly when I assigned $skip and $limit parameters to the native query. But I couldn't use order by statements such as "ORDER BY m.title DESC". My actual query is more complicated than this but I just wrote the basics version of the actual query.

**Repository**

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (m:Movie) RETURN m SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit;", countQuery = "MATCH (m:Movie) RETURN count(m);")
Page<Movie> getMoviesBy(Pageable pageable);
```

**Service**

```
return repository.getMoviesBy(pageable);
```

**Controller**

```
 @GetMapping("search")
    public ResponseEntity search(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNo,
                                 @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize,
                                 @RequestParam Sort.Direction sortDirection,
                                 @RequestParam String sortBy
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(movieService.search(PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize,Sort.by(sortDirection, sortBy))));
    }
```

Comment: `MATCH (m:Movie) WITH m ORDER BY m.title DESC RETURN m SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit`: does this work?

Comment: Yes, it works but I want to give m.title properties dynamically. @fbiville

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Just use SpEL.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.5/reference/html/#custom-queries.spel

Comment: Great, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use the the variable sortBy how parameter in the function service and repository, and use this variable for create a dinamic order in the native query.

Comment: should i use ORDER BY $sortBy like this? and which instance should this property be, is it Sort sortBy or String sortBy?

Comment: if you use a parameter like: thisisfunction(String order) in the query 
you have to do so in the query ORDER BY ?1